# batch script that runs with parameters read from a tab delimited text file (Linux)

Tags: linux, shell, batch-file

I have a tab delimited txt file that looks like this:

```
1. C1   34    98
2. C3    2    45
```

How can I make a batch script (linux) that will

extract the second data in the first line to variable 1

extract the third data in the first line to variable 2

extract the fourth data in the first line to variable 3

then

run a series of scripts with parmeters defined to variable 1,2 and 3

e.g.

```
script $1 $2 $3 > path/file$1-$2-$3
```

The script should use the values of variables as parameters and than write out the results to a file named according to the values of the variables, thus each cycle would result in a new file)

Finish the loop when all lines are used up from the tab limited txt file.

I am not a programmer...

Comment: What do you mean by extracting to variable1,2,3?

Answer (score 2):

This can be done in the shell alone(see below, assuming default value for [IFS](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html))

```
while read -r _ x y z ;
do 
   echo "$x" "$y" "$z"; 
done < input.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're using sh/bash/ksh, the shell gives you what you need:

```
while read dummy v1 v2 v3 dummy
do
   echo $v1 $v2 $v3
   ./dostuff $v1 $v2 $v3
done < inputFile
```

How a line is tokenised depends on the `IFS` variable, which by default consists of a tab, a space and a newline. You can change this, but you must manage its contents carefully as it's easy to break a script by not restoring IFS back to it's default values.

So what we're doing here is reading the file `inputFile` and splitting into five fields, dummy, v1, v2, v3, and dummy. These could have just as easily been called `a, b, c, d, e` but calling the fields we want to junk dummy it's obvious what the intention is.

If you know that the file will only ever have four fields, then the final `dummy` isn't needed (i.e., first line can be `while read dummy v1 v2 v3`); in essence the last field in the `while read [...]` sucks up the rest of the line, so if the input was `1. 34 45 12 67 65` then without the final `dummy` variable `v3` would contain `12 67 65`. With it, `v3` becomes `12` with the rest of the line being read into `dummy`. This'll make sense if you experiment with it :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
while read -r line
do
  var1=$(echo $line | awk '{print $2}')
  var2=$(echo $line | awk '{print $3}')
  var3=$(echo $line | awk '{print $4}')
  echo $var1 $var2 $var3
  ./yourscript.sh $var1 $var2 $var3
  # Do other stuff with these variables.
done < file
```

Comment: Thanks.I assume I define the name of the txt file in the last line (file). It is strange that it is in the end.

Comment: Yes. It is the way `while` statements are written in general. The `<` is the harbinger of the input file.

Comment: Using `<` means you don't get awarded a UUOC (useless use of cat) award :-)